# Set default system audio output port (for all accounts)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, ubuntu-10.04, pulse-audio

The default output audio port Ubuntu doesn't work on my system. It should be "Analog Mono Output/Amplifier", instead of "Analog Output/Amplifier". I can easily change that in sound preferences, just by choosing the right port in the "Output" tab. The problem is this would only apply to a single account, and I would like to change it system-wide, so it applies to all accounts on the system (I have more than 100 users...).

I'm after 2 hours of Googling, so any help would be appreciated.

**Update**: I can achieve the same effect as I would by changing it in sound preferences using the following command:

```
pacmd 'set-sink-port' 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.5.analog-stereo analog-output-mono;output-amplifier-on'
```

Unfortunately that's still not system-wide, so doesn't help me much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer, thanks to Ford_Perfect in #pulseaudio IRC channel.

I needed to add the following line to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
set-sink-port alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.5.analog-stereo analog-output-mono;output-amplifier-on
```

This solved the problem, but for some mysterious reason also made sound muted by default, and set default volume level at a very low. So as a workaround I added the following lines to the same file:

```
set-sink-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.5.analog-stereo False
set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.5.analog-stereo 30000
```

**One more important piece of information:** to use the above instructions you need your sink name (in my case `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.5.analog-stereo`) and name of your sink's ports (in my case I used `analog-output-mono;output-amplifier-on`). You can get them running `pacmd list-sinks` command - it will list all your avialiable sinks, together with their ports.

Comment: Do you know how can I map my line-in as analog-out? I am able to do that on Windows with Realtek panel but not on Linux so far. Only analog-output and analog-output-stereo are listed below 'ports' section in list-sinks command.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set *default-sink* in *pulse-client.conf*, see *man pulse-client.conf* but I didn't test that.

Comment: Looks good. I will test it out at work tomorrow.

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not right. I've got only one sink. What I want to do is to choose one of the sink's audio ports.